# How can i rotate a shape in a matrix by 90 degrees in C?

Tags: c, rotation

I have to write rotate function for tetris game. I have bricks in a txt file in a 10x10
dimensioned matrix and i need catch the brick location (L-shape) and rotate it 90ᵒ in clockwise.

input:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

and output must be like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

i could rotate whole matrix by 90 degrees but it was not like output. how can i just rotate L-shape? or how can i make output like this? thanks.

EDIT; here's the question: In this homework you are going to write rotate function of a tetris game. You have your bricks in a txt file in a 10x10
dimensioned matrix. You will catch the brick location and rotate it 90ᵒ in clockwise. For simplicity only two kinds of
bricks are going to be rotate by your algorithm. They are “L” character and the inverse of “L”. From the input file
you can take 4 different combinations of this two bricks. Your algorithm must rotate the brick in clockwise and
write the result matrix In an output file in the same location of your executable file.
The input file name is “input.txt” and the output file name is “output.txt”. Your program can rotate the brick in the
output file which it produced before, if it is given as an input.
The sample input and output files are in the attachment.

Comment: What do you mean "but it was not like output"? Anyway, you can rotate just the sub-matrix defined by the top-left corner of your L-shape sprite I guess.

Comment: ok but how can i make it? sorry im not good at this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for an algorithm. Then, I think you should first look at the pivot element. About which the rotation takes place. It seems that (4,4) element in the input is the pivot. Ofcourse, this depends on the shape. For a 90 degree clockwise rotation, just regenerate the shape about the pivot. And you will get the output.

Comment: thank you and one question more. the problem is i cant write an algorithm for pivot element. how can i find the point with code? do i think the all posibilities of shape? thanks again.

Comment: You can go through each element row by row, until you find an element that has two neighbouring "1"s. Then you do the magic with these "1"s. Basically taking different cases to see what the current state is.